# No such file or direcotory error during release config

Tags: iphone, sdk, release, config

```
/Users/madhukar/Desktop/wishstix/Classes/wishstixAppDelegate.h:11:0 /Users/madhukar/Desktop/wishstix/Classes/wishstixAppDelegate.h:11:32: error: FBConnect/FBSession.h: No such file or directory


/Users/madhukar/Desktop/wishstix/wishstix_Prefix.pch:13:0 In file included from /Users/madhukar/Desktop/wishstix/wishstix_Prefix.pch
```

I am including a group called FBConnect contains a bundle and header files, I included path in the header search path of the group works fine in debug mode, but getting 8 errors in release configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to make sure that the `Header Search Paths` configuration option is set for "All Configurations," not just "Debug."